# CSS How to I align a header with a height of 2em to the bottom

Tags: css

I would like to create a header that spans over 1 or two lines vertically. I would like to align these headers via the bottom line. I have created a jsfiddle page to demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S35Db/

HTML:

```
<h3>ABC</h3><h3>DEF JEH</h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
float:left;
border: 1px solid grey;
padding:10px;
margin: 5px;
max-width:3em;
height:3em;
```

}

What I would like to do is align the ABC to the JEH. How do I go about doing this? Do I need to create container around the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS :**

```
h3 {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width:3em;
    height:3em;
}

.bottom {
    line-height:65px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<h3 class="bottom">ABC</h3>
<h3>DEF JEH</h3>
```

Try this I think ie. what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide line-height to your first header.

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/S35Db/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to keep one container around it. Also remove float element and apply table-cell property like below.

```
div{display:table;height:3em;}

h3 {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding:10px;
margin: 5px;
max-width:3em;   
border: 1px solid grey;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: bottom;
display:table-cell;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S35Db/9/)